# Django ORM: Getting reverse dict

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have a `Chair` model with a `color` text field. I want to get a dict in the following format:

```
{'red': 53,
 'green': 1582,
 'cyan': 73}
```

Each number is the number of chair rows with that color, counting over all chairs in the database.

How can I do that using Django's ORM? (My database is Postgres, if that matters.)

Comment: Maybe this helps: `Chair.objects.all().values('color').annotate(count=Count("color"))`
and `from django.db.models import Count`

Comment: Doesn't work, I get `[{'count': 1, 'color': 'red'}, {'count': 1, 'color': 'blue'}, {'count': 1, 'color': 'blue'}...]`

Comment: @RamRachum try to add `.order_by()` at the end

Comment: @AndreyNelubin That worked! Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes but you can iterate over it to get what you wwant. And i think (not sure) you can't get it exactly like this using the ORM.

Comment: i didn't get what happend here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Chair.objects.all().values('color').annotate(count=Count("color")).order_by()
```

See more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by